# ggplot2 lines from point to point on xy are sorted

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to look at the path of an MCMC trace and the following plain `plot()` shows the sort of thing I am after, however, when I try the same in `ggplot2`, it unhelpfully sorts the x-axis values - which I might like in some circumstances, but not now.

```
set.seed(123)
t1 <- data.frame(x=rnorm(20), y=rnorm(20))
plot(t1$x, t1$y, type='b')
qplot(t1$x, t1$y, geom=c('point','line'))
```

How do I get something like in the `plot()` in `ggplot2`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `path` instead of `line`. `line` will connect points from smallest to largest x value but `path` will connect them in order as they are in data frame.

```
qplot(t1$x, t1$y, geom=c('point','path'))
```